# Find the rotational difference between two quaternions to calibrate two coordinate systems

Tags: c#, math, quaternions

I need to offset streaming quaternion data by a specific amount. To do this I plan to get the difference between the 2, then offset the first by the second.

I am having trouble finding the difference between the 2.

[Using this converter](http://quat.zachbennett.com/).

I am running this code:

```
public void convertQuat180()
{
    Quaternion q = new Quaternion(0.65328f, 0.2706f, 0.65328f, -0.2706f); //45,180,0

    Quaternion q180 = new Quaternion(0.70711f, 0, 0.70711f, 0);  // 0,90,0

    Quaternion result = q180 * Quaternion.Inverse(q);

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

I would expect `result` to be:

```
(euler) diff = 45, 90 , 0
```

But instead i get:

```
135,-180,0
```

Where am i going wrong here?

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes sense to imagine this using Euler angles. The difference rotation will most likely not have angles that are the difference of the two source rotations. Anyway, with the above formula, you get a rotation, such that `result * q = q180`. Isn't this what you wanted?

Comment: ok, maybe I should stick to quats to test. I am new to them, and have a much easier time imagining eulers! Is the above code valid to find the difference? And then how would I apply this difference to the original quat?

Comment: The problem of Euler angles is that the axes cannot be seen independently of each other. Sticking to quaternions or rotation matrices seems to be the better alternative for this scenario. You update a rotation represented by a quaternion by simple multiplication (see my first comment). But of course, this will get you back to the starting point.

Comment: ok, so, result in the above scenario, does equal q offset by q180?  Please excuse my quaternion ignorance!

Comment: That depends on what you mean by offset. And it depends on whether you rotate in a local coordinate system or the global one. Describe your actual problem to get more relevant answers.

Comment: I have an inertial sensor, mounted at an angle. I need the rotation values to be the same as the object it is mounted on. (A camera) . Due to the mounting system, there are rotational offsets between the sensor and the camera. So I have another sensor, held directly flat on the camera, and I take a snapshot of the values. I then need to use these values to offset the mounted sensor to match exactly the camera rotation. Does that make sense? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is a transformation of coordinate systems. You have a rotation measured by the sensor `RS` and a rotation of the camera `RC`. Both are related by a constant (let's call it) offset `RO`:

```
RS = RC * RO
```

Or alternatively

```
RC = RS * RO^-1
```

During your calibration procedure, you acquire `RS` and `RC`. Then, you can calculate the offset as:

```
RO = RC^-1 * RS
RO^-1 = RS^-1 * RC
```

Just calculate the one that you will use more often (probably `RO^-1` because you want to get the camera rotation from the sensor rotation).

Comment: Thank you! `^` is `power of`, is that right? What would this look like in code? (once again, please forgive my math ignorance)

Comment: The notation `^-1` is the inverse.

Comment: ah i see. So, your equation above would be:

`RO = Quaternion.Inverse(RC) * RS;`

and then i can simply use `Quaternion.Inverse(RO) ;` to get the value i want?

Comment: Either this or calculate `RO^-1` directly: `ROInverse = Quaternion.Inverse(RS) * RC`.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much for your time/help. Much appreciated.

Comment: Great answer, Thanks!