# How to calculate difference between two spatial rotations

Tags: javascript, math, quaternions, gl-matrix

I'm trying to convert physical orientation of a mobile device got from [`deviceorientation`](https://www.w3.org/TR/orientation-event/#deviceorientation) event to a series of camera rotations in my sort of 3D viewer. The problem is that I need to do spatial rotation **relative to the first orientation** taken from `deviceorientation` i.e. the orientation on page load. So I need to save the first orientation and then somehow do spatial rotation corresponding to orientation change from the saved one to the current.

How do I do that?

Note that I use [glMatrix](https://github.com/toji/gl-matrix)'s quaternions to do spatial rotation but I'm not quite familiar with this topic.

Currently my rotation function looks like this:

```
function rotate(aX, aY, aZ) {
    var rotation = quat.create();
    quat.rotateX(rotation, rotation, aX);
    quat.rotateY(rotation, rotation, aY);
    quat.rotateZ(rotation, rotation, aZ);
    quat.normalize(rotation, rotation);
    ...
}
```

And my `deviceorientation` listener looks like this (sure it's not finished yet):

```
var aInitial = null;
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function (event) {
    var alpha = e.alpha, beta = e.beta, gamma = e.gamma;
    if (!aInitial) aInitial = [alpha, beta, gamma];
    // somehow get angles aX, aY, aZ from alpha, beta, gamma and aInitial
    rotate(aX, aY, aZ);
});
```

I guess that it's quite hard to find explicit formula to get needed angles (`aX, aY, aZ`). I guess that I need to do quaternion transformations instead but I don't know how exactly.

Comment: Use the quaternion or matrix quotient (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39192856/find-the-rotational-difference-between-two-quaternions-to-calibrate-two-coordina/39193456#39193456). If you need other representations, convert the quaternion.

Comment: @Nico Schertler Thanks for advice. But how do I create a quaternion from rotation angles (`aX, aY, aZ`)?

Comment: Aren't you already doing that (`quat.rotateX(...)`)?

Comment: Yes, it's obvious: create quaternion by series of `rotate*` calls