# Rotating from one quarternion to another

Tags: c++, math, 3d, geometry, rotation

Ok so this question might be a little complicated

Basically I have an imu off which I am able to read quartenions, I want to be able to set a quarternion as home, and then from any other quarternion i want to be able to calculate the the rotations required to return the imu's orintation back to the home reading. Once these rotations are discovered I need to convert them into degrees on the plane made up by x and y as I have a method of displaying which direction the imu should be tilted to 'head home' on the plane

edit: I have added a diagram to try and show what I mean

[image]

for this given senario, I had a version that was working and used Eular, however it would suffer from the gimble lock issue, so as such I'm wanting this to stay as quarternions if possible

the solution I already tried to solve this problem didn't work sadly (with it returning degree readings that seemed right at first but got worse and worse as I rotated the sensor around) but is as follows:

. I got the quarternion at my desired home lets call it q_home

. I got the inverse of home and multiplied it against the following quarternion: inverse of q_home * (1,0,0,0) I believed that this would give me an offset which I could then later apply to another quartenion to find it's difference in position to home relative to (1,0,0,0)

. I would then move the sensor and as I said get the current quarternion and add the offset

. I then normalise the result and calculate the angle in degrees using the following formula (atan2(result.y, result.x) * (180 / PI))

Comment: Ok and where exactly in this process do you have problems? Have you already tried something? Also I don't get the thing with the xy-plane. Is the IMU mounted on a single axis? Maybe a layout sketch would be suitable as an appendix to this question.

Comment: You can simply [calculate rotational differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39192856/find-the-rotational-difference-between-two-quaternions-to-calibrate-two-coordina/39193456#39193456). If you need an Euler representation, simply convert the quaternion to Euler angles. But it may be hard to interpret.

Comment: @JakobStark I have tried to add more details. Thankyou for the replys

Comment: @NicoSchertler I'll try and see if this works for me tonight as I have to go to work rn. Thankyou for the replys

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.